# Error 200 when performing checkout using TortoiseSvn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to performa simple checkout operation. This works on several other computers (not in the same LAN though). I get this error message:

http://www.jamamate.com/error.jpg

Comment: I'm getting a 404 from your link...

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy server, HTTP Error 200 may indicate that the proxy does not support WebDAV or has WebDAV disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would first check your firewall/antivirus software, which may mangle the data received by subversion. To confirm whether this is the case or not, see if disabling either of them changes anything.

If it still does not work, then I would check your proxy settings if you are behind a proxy.